# Get list of users in quickblox chat

Tags: ios, iphone, chat, quickblox

i need to get how to do implement this
i want a particular user to be the admin, if the admin logs in then
all users in my Quickblox account displays in the UserFragment class(which is the default),
if other user logs in, the UserFragment class should only display the admin.
Which means the admin can chat with other users and other users can only chat with the admin.

Answer (score 3):

```
 [QBRequest logInWithUserEmail:@"adminEmail" password:@"adminPassword" successBlock:^(QBResponse * _Nonnull response, QBUUser * _Nullable user) {
     //You get userid of admin in user.ID

     if(user.ID == 1234567){ //Pass ID of your admin which you can take from https://admin.quickblox.com 
         // Fetch all users                      
     }else{
         // Retrieve user by ID for admin
     } 
 errorBlock:^(QBResponse * _Nonnull response) {
         // Handle error               
  }];
```

Now, for fetching all users you can use.

```
QBGeneralResponsePage *page = [QBGeneralResponsePage responsePageWithCurrentPage:1 perPage:10];

[QBRequest usersForPage:page successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBGeneralResponsePage *pageInformation, NSArray *users) {

     // Successful response contains current page infromation + list of users

 } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
     // Handle error
}];
```

Now, for fetching admin details.

```
//Pass your admin ID here
[QBRequest usersWithIDs:@[@12345] page:[QBGeneralResponsePage responsePageWithCurrentPage:1 perPage:10] successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBGeneralResponsePage *page, NSArray *users) {

      // Details of admin in users
 } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
      // Handle error here
 }];
```

You can also refer this link for fetching users

https://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-ios#Retrieving_all_Users